# How to refresh one random UITableViewCell of UITableView x times every x seconds. Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nstimer

I'm working on a game with a Table View.

That's the idea of the app:

I push a button starting a timer and I fill up the cells of the Table View with random images. I'm using 7 cells and 5 images. Depending of the cell I touch, I earn different points.  In 5 seconds I want show 5 different cells (1 second, 1 cell shown). Each time I show a cell, I hide the others cells and I have the possibility of touch this cell and earn Points. After these 5 seconds, I would like change the content of the Table View.

I know how unhide only one cell and hide the others with the hidden property.

The problem is I only have managed show the cells changing the data of the Table View every 1 second but not after 5 seconds.

Steps I do

1) Starts the timer. Every 5 seconds I call refreshTable

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(refreshTable) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

2) In refreshTable I fill up one Array with 7 new objects. Every object is an UIImage. I get the 7 UIImages from an array of 53 UIImages. And I refresh the Table to fill up the Rows with the new images.

```
-(void)refreshTable
{


    self.valueImage=arc4random() % 52;

    self.value=arc4random() % [self.wackArray count];


    for (int n=0 ;n<7 ; n++){

        int random=arc4random() % 52;


        [self.randomArrayIndex addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", random]];
        int objectRandomArray = [[self.randomArrayIndex objectAtIndex:n] integerValue];

        [self.randomArrayImage insertObject:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:objectRandomArray] atIndex:n];

    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [self.randomArrayIndex removeAllObjects];

}
```

To manage the time do I need a nest the `NSTimer` or use a `performSelector`? And to show the cells I have to use `retriveCellForIndexPath` or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`?

Its posible to call `setNeedsDisplay` to refresh/show the Cells?

Comment: What is a hidden cell ?

Comment: I hide the row I want with the hidden property.  if (indexPath.row == self.value){
        cell.hidden=NO;
        
    }else{
        cell.hidden=YES;
        
    }

Comment: Alright, then you can get all the visible cells and update their `hidden` properties, also save the information about the state of all datasource items somewhere so that the datasource methods can set the correct values when needed. Do it all on the main thread synchronously as any other kind of datasource manipulation. So what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: Im going to try this solution. Thanks!!

Comment: The problem is that I know how to show only one cell every 1 second, but Im calling reloadData of the Table View every second, I would like to call reloadData only after 5 seconds and show every second the cell I want unhide with the specified data that Ive put in the Table. The data of the Table has to change after 5 seconds.

Comment: Don't call `reloadData` if you don't want to. The documentation of `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` describes an alternative for how to update particular cells with or without user notification.

Comment: The thing is that I dont want reload the cell. I only want show it without change its data

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much indeed! I tried your solution and worked ;)

Comment: no problem, please add some information of what you used exactly as an answer and accept it, there's a change it will help someone in the future.

Comment: I added the implementation of my method ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's my final refreshTable method. I awaked that I didn't used UICollectionViewCells.

```
-(void)refreshTable
```

{

```
    self.tableView.hidden=NO;

   //count returns number of cells
   self.value=arc4random() % [self.wackArray count];

   [self.tableView beginUpdates];

   NSIndexPath *indexPath0 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath3 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath4 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath5 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:0];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath6 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:6 inSection:0];

   UITableViewCell *cell0=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath0];
   UITableViewCell *cell1=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath1];
   UITableViewCell *cell2=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath2];
   UITableViewCell *cell3=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath3];
   UITableViewCell *cell4=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath4];
   UITableViewCell *cell5=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath5];
   UITableViewCell *cell6=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath6];

   cell0.hidden=YES;
   cell1.hidden=YES;
   cell2.hidden=YES;
   cell3.hidden=YES;
   cell4.hidden=YES;
   cell5.hidden=YES;
   cell6.hidden=YES;

   cell0.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
   cell1.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
   cell2.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
   cell3.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
   cell4.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
   cell5.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
   cell6.userInteractionEnabled=NO;


   NSIndexPath *indexPathRandom = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.value inSection:0];
   UITableViewCell *cellRandom=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathRandom];

   cellRandom.hidden=NO;
   cellRandom.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

   [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

}

Comment: It has a large room for improvements but I'm glad it works for you, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understand your question, you want to show just one cell for a time (ie 1 minute) and hide it again.

You can create a derived class from UICollectionViewCell and use them in your collectionViewDataSource.
Then, on your timer, you can use a NSIndexPath to get the wanted cell and tell it to animate for a certain time;

As example :

CollectionViewDataSource.m

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell configureForItem:YourObjectToConfigure];
    return cell;
}



-(void)refreshTable
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:ROW inSection:SECTION];
    [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] animate];
}
```

MyCell.h

```
@interface MyCell : UICollectionViewCell
-(void) configureForItem:(NSObject*) item;
-(void) animate;

@end
```

MyCell.m

```
 @implementation MyCell
 -(void) configureForItem:(NSObject*) item{
        // Do your configuration stuff
 }

 -(void) animate{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
                  // Do your show stuff
            } completion:^{
                  // Do your hide stuff
            }];
  }
 @end
```

Comment: I want to show a different cell 5 times in 5 seconds. Thanks a lot for your answer :D

Comment: Ok, sorry i misunderstood your question.
You can use NSTimer to activate your animation.

prefer use retriveCellForIndexPath than reloadRowsAtIndexPaths, because it will reload all the tableView and so the layout may be refreshed. (That will be seen as a little flash in your app)

Comment: Thanks mate, I was able to finish it. ;)